# Android Set ImageView in front of Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` in my Android App. Now I want to show an `ImageView` in front of that Layout. The problem is that the `ImageView` is not in the front, it's a bit transparent and I can see things like `EditText` and `Button`. I can't change the Layout (setContentView), because the Layout is created dynamically and after `setContentView`, the Controls are away.

Comment: please post the layout if you can

Comment: I agree. Please could you post the layout and also a picture of what it looks like currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add view programmatically, and in the way that it will be on the top!

1. create id for you top level layout
2. Now some code (in my case it's relative layout):

   ```
   RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_id);
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context)  
   Drawable rightArrowBlackDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image); 
   imageView.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
   relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
   imageView.bringToFront();    

   //here just example layout params, use yours params ;-) 
   private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams getLayoutParams() {

       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
       new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,             
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

       layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
       return layoutParams;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to try it until now.

Answer (score 1):

You can bring it to the front once you insert it.

```
imageView.bringToFront();
```

If the image is transparent, you can set a white background to prevent things below it from showing.

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
```